# What's a good way to algorithmically eliminate outliers in a set of measurements?

Tags: repeated-measures, measurement-error, measurement

I'm trying to benchmark some code as quickly as possible while still getting the result with under a specified error.

To do that, I'm using a system timer to sample a loop running my code and I'm counting the number of iterations that occurred within the sampling period.

I aggregate these measurements into a data set of a given minimal size, calculate their mean and error ( `error = SQRT( SUM( (x_i-mean)^2 ) / (n * (n-1)))` ) and continue expanding the set and recalculating the values until I'm under the specified error (wiki says to reduce the error x times, I need to expand the sample size x$^2$ times so I'm trusting it and doing that).

From looking at the data, I'm getting fairly stable results but occasionally there are spikes (I suppose some of the 90 million lines of Linux kernel source code occasionally do something), which probably could be eliminated so I could get a more accurate measurement.

What's a good algorithm for eliminating such outliers? Is there a better method I can use to process my data?

Here's what some of my [example data](https://pastebin.com/hi0yeHLe) looks like:

[image]

Comment: By eliminating such outliers, you are biasing the results--in effect, denying that those outliers exist.  More subtly, by running your tests until you achieve a particular error target, you are biasing the estimate of the error.  These considerations suggest you would be better served by asking how to perform the benchmarking rather than how to improve a fundamentally flawed procedure.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. I welcome any suggestions on how to improve the measurement.

Comment: The graphic is intriguing. It raises an important question: what are you doing to test your hypothesis that it is *system events* rather than *inherent variations in your code* causing these spikes?  Could the code performance vary with different input? Are you varying the input in your testing (as you should) or not?  Have you considered running the code multiple times at random occasions with *exactly* the same input so you can assess the variation caused by the system? In brief, I am suggesting your problem might be solved with a good experimental design rather than automatic data deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an entire field of research dedicated to outlier detection, so there are too many options to list, ranging from very simple to very complex.

A very simple method is to calculate a threshold (say, mean +/- 3 s.d.) and toss out anything outside that range. If the spikes are extremely different, it will be easy to identify them.

However, as a commenter noted, you may bias your results. If these 'spikes' are just part of the environment, you might leave them in. If they are truly irrelevant to what you wish to measure, throw them out.

Comment: Thanks. I'm basically only dealing with upwards spikes which should be caused by system events. Since I want to measure the speed of only the code, not average performance on my system over a period of time, I think the upwards spikes are best eliminated. The remaining fluctuations should be errors in my timings, which I believe, belong in the error calculation. The data set expansion until the error fits my requirement was likely a bad idea on my part. I should just be eliminating the outliers.